# Why Job class is randomly cached?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

When the Job Class is dispatched via Laravel, it is randomly using old code of Job Class that is no longer exist. Everytime I dispatch it is random between old code and new code.

I am not running any worker in the background. I am simply using `php artisan queue:listen` on terminal.

I even tried to destroy box and recreate new one in homestead, still same issue.

Here what I tried (without success!):

- php artisan queue:restart
- php artisan cache:clear
- destroy box and recreate new one in homestead
- download latest homestead and homestead box.

I am using postman to submit a post request, in a controller it `dispatch()` a job. I even tried directly on Firefox as well.

Like I mention it is random between old Job Class code and updated Job Class code.

When I tested on another PC (Windows) with homestead installed - it is working fine without any issue. The project code is identical (git pull).

What it went wrong?